# Is it possible to bound trait function type in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I would like to make a trait with one function. For this function, I would like to bound the signature according to a predefined type. Is this possible to do in Rust?

Here is an example:

```
type FuncType = fn(u64) -> u64;

pub trait MyTrait {
    fn my_func(u64) -> u64;
}
```

Basically, in this example I would like to set that the `my_func` has the type FuncType but without writing it explicitly, so that if `FuncType` changes in the future I need to change it only in one place. Is something like this possible to do?

Comment: No. You can always only kick this down the road. But you'll  have to touch the function anyways when `FuncType` changes, so I don't think this is that big of a deal.

Comment: It may be possible to create a kind of static assertion to enforce this restriction, though.

Comment: You could probably do this with a macro but that would be so much overkill for something so simple.

Comment: Thanks guys! I was trying to imagine different approaches how to do this, but also could not come to any good idea. @PitaJ can you point me to an example of this?